# Is there a way to generate database by writing PHP?

Tags: php, database

Is there a way to generate SQLite3 database by writing PHP with no SQL?

Somewhat like django's models.

Comment: Do you mean, writing a binary file in SQLite format? Without using SQLite?

Comment: Somewhat like django's models, create the sqlite binary automaticly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to write SQL, a possibility is to use an abstraction layer, like the [**Doctrine ORM**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

It will allow to manipulate objects, on the PHP side -- and will deal with the database-related stuff *(including compatibility between several types of SQL databases)*.

Answer (score 0):

No, to create a database, you're going to need to use SQL at some point unless you're using a Database Manager. If you're using PHP, you can use the built in libraries for accessing databases, found here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create database using PHP built in libraries. Provided your hosting server allows.....